# typeof: how to get type from string

Tags: c#, .net

I've many objects, each of which I have information in string about its type.
like:

```
string stringObjectType = "DateTime";
```

While running, I have no object itself.
So I can not test it `typeof (object)`

How can I get while running the type of the object by:

```
typeof (stringObjectType)
```

Comment: Will you have the strings as `DateTime` or `System.DateTime`?

Comment: Is this what you need? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx

Comment: To be precise, you cannot write `typeof(object)`. You can pass a class name only. Use `object.GetType` instead. Just saying.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a System.Type from a type name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179102/getting-a-system-type-from-a-type-name)

Comment: also helpfull: [Getting a fully qualified type name from a string .Net C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592706/getting-a-fully-qualified-type-name-from-a-string-net-c-sharp?rq=1)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
try
{
    // Get the type of a specified class.
    Type myType1 = Type.GetType("System.DateTime");
    Console.WriteLine("The full name is {myType1.FullName}.");

    // Since NoneSuch does not exist in this assembly, GetType throws a TypeLoadException.
    Type myType2 = Type.GetType("NoneSuch", true);
    Console.WriteLine("The full name is {myType2.FullName}.");
}
catch(TypeLoadException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

See [`Type.GetType(string)` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx)

Comment: While this code is correct. Does it answer his question? string stringObjectType = "DateTime"; will not get the correct type here.

Comment: I believe it was only an example

Comment: The question was about getting a type by its' name, what is wrong with my answer?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with you answer, you got an upvote from me ^^

Comment: Also, this is just copy/pasted from MSDN, without any explanation or indication of source

Comment: @DominicKexel +1. Didn't know it.

Comment: @DominicKexel so what? It's self explanatory there are comments there. Seriously people, ease up

Comment: @animaonline I didn't downvote, I just said it's missing any indication of source, so one could call it plagiarism.

Comment: And regardless of how correct the actual code is.. It still doesnt work with the information OP provided.

Comment: Dont get me wrong. Im not the one downvoting here... Im just telling you its not an answer to the question at hand.

Comment: +1 for the answer, since now the Answer has the link from MSDN as well, for `DateTime`, @HardLuck, can edit the answer with a line `Type myType1 = Type.GetType("System.DateTime");` to make it a complete answer, But I think the answer points to the core which is `Type.GetType`

Answer (score 26):

You can use `Type.GetType()` to get a type from its string name. So you can do:

```
Type DateType = Type.GetType("System.DateTime");
```

You can't just use "DateTime" since that's not the type's name. If you do this and the name is wrong (it doesn't exist) then it'll throw an exception. So you'll need a try/catch around this.

You can get the proper type name for any given object by doing:

```
string TypeName = SomeObject.GetType().FullName;
```

If you need to use vague or incomplete names, then you're going to have a fun time messing around with reflection. Not impossible, but certainly a pain.