# Super type of generic object

Tags: c#, generics

i got a class like

```
class Btree<T> where T : IComparable { }
```

Now i want to write a controller that depending on the input creates an object.
But i don't want to rewrite the code for all possible types.
So i need something like:

```
Btree t = null;
if(input == "int") 
t = new Btree<int>();
if(input == "string")
t = new Btree<string>();
```

After that i want to treat t no matter what type the btree actually is. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [typeof: how to get type from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108786/typeof-how-to-get-type-from-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question literally: Yes, you can do that using reflection. See the following question for details.

- [Pass An Instantiated System.Type as a Type Parameter for a Generic Class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/266115/87698)

However, you *shouldn't* do that. Generics are a tool for *compile-time type safety*. If you don't need that (and from your example, it looks like you don't), simply using a `Btree<IComparable>` might be the most fitting solution for your problem:

```
var t = new Btree<IComparable>();
```

Comment: object however does not implement IComparable and i need that since i have to compare on the key which is of type T

Comment: @tuxmania: Good point; use a `Btree<IComparable>` then. (I modified my answer.)

Comment: still Btree<int> is not castable to Btree<IComparable>

Comment: @tuxmania: Correct. My point is that - from your example - it looks like you don't need a `Btree<int>` *at all*. Instead of the example in your question, just use `Btree t = new Btree<IComparable>()`.

Comment: ok you are right but indeed i need it :) since i have to sort at some point the keys and it is different sorting 1 as int or as string.   Btree t = new Btree<something>() also does not work since Btree requires the generic parameter

Comment: @tuxmania: IComparable contains everything you need for sorting. Or do you need a custom sort order for strings?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122142/discussion-between-heinzi-and-tuxmania).

Comment: Solution indeed was to just use the super type as generic parameter that is IComparable in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

Your "Btree t = null;" line is not valid to start if it is really a generic class.

BTree cannot be both generic and not generic at the same time.  If it is a generic the type must be defined upon declaration of the variable "t".